# How to get the lowest and highest price of products by id?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

hey guys let's say I have 10 products

how can I get the lowest price of them and the highest price of them too?

I have $products_ids which has all the products id's

```
$products_price_desc = get_posts( array( 
              'post_type' => 'product',
              'numberposts' => -1,
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'orderby'           => 'price',
               'order' => 'DESC'
              'fields' => 'ids',
              ));

$products_price_asc = get_posts( array( 
              'post_type' => 'product',
              'numberposts' => -1,
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'orderby'           => 'price',
               'order' => 'ASC'
              'fields' => 'ids',
              ));
```

And now How I can get the min and max price value of them? and to use here

> $max_price= $products_price_desc;
>
> $min_price= $products_price_asc;

```
    <input type="range" min="<?php echo $min_price ?>" 
                        max="<?php echo $max_price ?>">
```

Comment: Can you describe your question more and also share the table structure so it might help to give an answer to your question.

Comment: @Rabby I'm trying to get the min price and max price of my products

Comment: @Rabby please check the question again.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is `select min(price) as min_price, max(price) as max_price from products`

Comment: @GuidoFaecke and how to do that? can you kindly write what your mind as code

Comment: I was thinking of a custom sql query. A good starting point could be `->get_results(<your_custom_sql>)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the order_by parameter, and the name of the property as the value ("price", if I'm not mistaken):

```
    'orderby'           => 'price',
```

[Here's a list](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/) of the other parameters you can apply to your query.